# Toolbar button is clickable even after disabling

Tags: syncfusion

I have checked your documentation could manage to dynamically disable (enable false) of my toolbar button.

```
this.toolBarObject.enableItems(document.getElementById('add'), false);
```

The 'Add' buttons appears as if it's disabled, but it is still triggering click events when clicked.

Is there a way to disallow clicking on disabled buttons?

Note: I am talking about toolbar alone but not the toolbar in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the reported case and toolbar buttons are disabled after calling disable method. Kindly refer the below sample.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsuudm-bcsfwa?file=app.component.html

```
onSubmit(): void {this.toolObj.disable(true);}
```

Comment: the question here is to disable one item in the toolbar (button) not the entire toolbar.